# MEMS microphone pinout identification

Tags: pinout, mems-microphone

I wanted to play with MEMS micrphones. I didn't wanted to wait for my order to arrive so I decided to take away some microphones in some computers in the dumpster.

I removed it using hot air to find a layout similar to the one of [IMP23ABSU](https://www.st.com/en/mems-and-sensors/imp23absu.html).

[image]

How to identify the pinout ? Is there a standard like for op amp ? Could I check it using standard tools ?

Answer (score 2):

Pin configuration varies from vendor to vendor. Below is the pin configuration from [Knowles mems microphone](https://www.knowles.com/docs/default-source/model-downloads/spw0690lm4h-1-datasheet-rev-a.pdf?Status=Master&sfvrsn=4cbd77b1_4).This is completely different from ST which you
mentioned in your the post.

**Knowles PINOUT**

[image]

**ST PINOUT**

[image]

Comment: Would there be a way to identify Vdd and GND ? GND seems to always sits around the hole.

Comment: You are correct, GND seems to always sits around the hole.VDD can vary